# Efficient enumeration of ordered subsets in Python

Tags: python, iterator, generator, combinations, python-itertools

I'm not sure of the appropriate mathematical terminology for the code I'm trying to write.  I'd like to generate combinations of unique integers, where "ordered subsets" of each combination are used to exclude certain later combinations.

Hopefully an example will make this clear:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
​
mylist = range(4)
max_depth = 3

rev = chain.from_iterable(combinations(mylist, i) for i in xrange(max_depth, 0, -1))
for el in list(rev):
    print el
```

---

That code results in output that contains all the subsets I want, but also some extra ones that I do not.  I have manually inserted comments to indicate which elements I don't want.

```
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 3)
(0, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
(0, 1)  # Exclude: (0, 1, _) occurs as part of (0, 1, 2) above
(0, 2)  # Exclude: (0, 2, _) occurs above
(0, 3)  # Keep
(1, 2)  # Exclude: (1, 2, _) occurs above
(1, 3)  # Keep: (_, 1, 3) occurs above, but (1, 3, _) does not
(2, 3)  # Keep
(0,)    # Exclude: (0, _, _) occurs above
(1,)    # Exclude: (1, _, _) occurs above
(2,)    # Exclude: (2, _) occurs above
(3,)    # Keep
```

---

Thus, the desired output of my generator or iterator would be:

```
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 3)
(0, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 3)
(0, 3)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)
(3,)
```

I know I could make a list of all the (wanted and unwanted) combinations and then filter out the ones I don't want, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient, generator or iterator based way.

Comment: You can hash all of the subsets into a dictionary.   So if you generate (0, 1, 2) write a method to hash {(0,): True, (1,): True, (0, 1): True, (0, 2): True, (0, 1, 2): True } and so on.  Then you can look up in this hash table to see if you want the new set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to exclude any combination that is a *prefix* of a previously-returned combination. Doing so is straightforward.

- If a tuple `t` has length `max_depth`, it can't be a prefix of a previously-returned tuple, since any tuple it's a prefix of would have to be longer.
- If a tuple `t` ends with `mylist[-1]`, then it can't be a prefix of a previously-returned tuple, since there are no elements that could legally be added to the end of `t` to extend it.
- If a tuple `t` has length less than `max_depth` and does not end with `mylist[-1]`, then `t` is a prefix of the previously-returned tuple `t + (mylist[-1],)`, and `t` should not be returned.

Thus, the combinations you should generate are exactly the ones of length `max_depth` and the shorter ones that end with `mylist[-1]`. The following code does so, in exactly the same order as your original code, and correctly handling cases like `maxdepth > len(mylist)`:

```
def nonprefix_combinations(iterable, maxlen):
    iterable = list(iterable)
    if not (iterable and maxlen):
        return
    for comb in combinations(iterable, maxlen):
        yield comb
    for length in xrange(maxlen-2, -1, -1):
        for comb in combinations(iterable[:-1], length):
            yield comb + (iterable[-1],)
```

(I've assumed here that in the case where `maxdepth == 0`, you still don't want to include the empty tuple in your output, even though for `maxdepth == 0`, it isn't a prefix of a previously-returned tuple. If you do want the empty tuple in this case, you can change `if not (iterable and maxlen)` to `if not iterable`.)

Comment: This works great. Thanks so much for your help! As I mentioned in a comment to @hgwell's, your solution and @hgwell's yield the same results, but interestingly, in a different order. I did a few quick speed tests with `line_profiler` and your solutions were about the same in terms of speed. Thanks much for the vocab help (_prefix_) also.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed an interesting pattern in your desired output and I have a generator that produces that. Does this work for all your cases?

```
from itertools import combinations

def orderedSetCombination(iterable, r):
    # Get the last element of the iterable
    last = (iterable[-1], )
    # yield all the combinations of the iterable without the
    # last element
    for iter in combinations(iterable[:-1], r):
        yield iter
    # while r > 1 reduce r by 1 and yield all the combinations
    while r>1:
        r -= 1
        for iter in combinations(iterable[:-1], r):
            yield iter+last
    # yield the last item
    yield last

iter = [0,1,2,3]

for el in (list(orderedSetCombination(iter, 3))):
    print(el)
```

Here is my explaination of the logic:

```
# All combinations that does not include the last element of the iterable
# taking r = max_depth items at a time

(0,1,2) 

# from here on, its the combinations of all the elements except 
# the last element and the last element is added to it.
# so here taking r = r -1 items at a time and adding the last element
# combinations([0,1,2], r=2)

(0,1,3)
(0,2,3)
(1,2,3)

# the only possible value right now at index r = 2 is the last element (3)
# since all possible values of (0,1,_) (0,2,_) (1,2,_) are already listed
# So reduce r by 1 again and continue: combinations([0,1,2], r=1)

(0, 3)
(1, 3)
(2, 3)

# continue until r == 0 and then yield the last element

(3,)
```

Comment: This works great.  Thanks so much for your help!  Your solution and @user2357112's yield the same results, but interestingly, in a different order.   I did a few quick speed tests with `line_profiler` and your solutions were about the same.  FYI your function needs sliceable objects, not just any `iterable` in the `iterable` argument.